# GZip сжатие статических json-файлов на IIS

Tags: json, iis, windows-server, gzip

Имеется приложение на php, развернутое на Win2012/IIS 8.
Время от времени планировщик задач перегенерирует несколько JSON-файлов, расположенных в директории `./cache/` проекта.
Для файлов настроено кэширование сервера, а вот теперь неплохо бы добавить к кэшированию еще и сжатие.

Насколько из различных статетй понятно, то если файл сжат, то в кэше хранится сжатая копия. Но вот что-то не совсем ясно, как это сжатие настроить.
На текущий момент времени json-файлы передаются несжатыми (там же есть и Html файл, он передается сжатым) конфиг следующий:

```
<caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
    <profiles>
        <add extension=".json" policy="DontCache" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
        <add extension=".html" policy="DontCache" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:01:00" />
    </profiles>
</caching>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" />
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
   <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
   <dynamicTypes>
   </dynamicTypes>
   <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
   </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Comment: А просто положить .json.gz файл рядом не катит?

Comment: @eri речь не про `.gz` архив, а про заголовки `Accept-Encoding` запроса и соответствующий ответ, если там присутствует gzip. Фактически сжать файл я могу и при генерации, но тогда нужно отдавать соответствующий заголовок ответа для него.

Comment: С иис не работал, но остальные сервера, даже самые урезанные отдают архив вместо файла, если он лежит рядом. Такой метод используют js библиотеки.. Особых настроек нигде не делал. Только gzip on

Comment: что-то настройка того же в `applicationHost.config` не помогла. хотя вроде пишут что должно работать

Comment: ерунда какая-то, добавил настройку через appcmd.exe , один раз сработало, получил gzip заголовки размер переданного видно, что меньше. Но после опять обычные файлы стал отдавать.

Answer (score 0):

В общем говоря, закончилось все дело выполнением команды

```
C:\Windows\System32\Inetsrv\Appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"staticTypes.[mimeType='application/json',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
```

которая добавляет компрессию `json` для статических файлов на уровне сервера, а не сайта. После перезапуска пула приложения вроде стал отдавать сжатые данные (26кбайт -> 4.5, 51 -> 12, 197 -> 33), что в целом весомо для мобильных клиентов с плохой связью.